# Python Seaborn Matplotlib setting line style as legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the following plot build with seaborn using `factorplot()` method.

Is it possible to use the line style as a legend to replace the legend based on line color on the right?  [image]

```
graycolors = sns.mpl_palette('Greys_r', 4)
g = sns.factorplot(x="k", y="value", hue="class", palette=graycolors,
                   data=df, linestyles=["-", "--"])
```

Furthermore I'm trying to get both lines in black color using the `color="black"` parameter in my factorplot method but this results in an exception "factorplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'". How can I paint both lines in the same color and separate them by the linestyle only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been looking for a solution trying to put the linestyle in the legend like [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes), but I have not yet found how to do this in seaborn. However, to make the data clear in the legend I have used different [markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# creating some data
n = 11
x = np.linspace(0,2, n)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.cos(2*np.pi*x)
data = {'x': np.append(x, x), 'y': np.append(y, y2),
        'class': np.append(np.repeat('sin', n), np.repeat('cos', n))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot the data with the markers
# note that I put the legend=False to move it up (otherwise it was blocking the graph)
g=sns.factorplot(x="x", y="y", hue="class", palette=graycolors,
                 data=df, linestyles=["-", "--"], markers=['o','v'], legend=False)
# placing the legend up
g.axes[0][0].legend(loc=1)
# showing graph
plt.show()
```

[image: the graph]

Answer (score 4):

you can try the following:

```
h = plt.gca().get_lines()
lg = plt.legend(handles=h, labels=['YOUR Labels List'], loc='best')
```

It worked fine with me.