# Not able to change linestyle in Seaborn plot

Tags: seaborn, linestyle

I have a dataframe modified from iris dataset where there is 1 numeric and 2 categorical columns:

```
       PL     Species group
  4.400  versicolor     A
  1.600      setosa     B
  5.600   virginica     A
  4.700  versicolor     B
  6.100   virginica     B
```

I want to plot a seaborn lineplot with lines in black color and with different linestyle for each Species.  I tried following codes:

```
sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', 
         color='k', style='Species'); plt.show()
sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', 
         color='k', hue_kws=dict(ls=['-','-.','.'])); plt.show()
sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', 
         color='k', linestyle='Species'); plt.show()
sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', 
         color='k', linestyle='Species', style='Species'); plt.show()
sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', 
         color='k', linestyle='Species', style='Species', dashes='Species'); plt.show()
```

However, they all plot solid lines only:

[image]

Why I am not able to change linestyle in this code?

Comment: `linestyles` work! If you enter your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Another option would be to use `lineplot` here.

Comment: Yes, I also found that option. That's also a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`sns.pointplot()` docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html), `linestyles=` (plural) can provide a line style for each of the hue values.

Note that the linestyle isn't (yet) shown in the legend. See e.g. [issue 2005](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2005) or [Seaborn setting line style as legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663613/python-seaborn-matplotlib-setting-line-style-as-legend). The suggested workaround is to also set different markers, which do show up in the legend. Or to create legend handles via `ax.get_lines()`.

The following way to create the legend would need some adaption if more elements would be plotted into the same subplot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_str = '''     PL     Species group
  4.400  versicolor     A
  1.600      setosa     B
  1.600      setosa     A
  5.600   virginica     A
  4.700  versicolor     B
  6.100   virginica     B'''
rnegdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)

ax = sns.pointplot(data=rnegdf, x='group', y='PL', hue='Species', color='k',
                   linestyles=['-', '-.', ':'])
point_handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=[(line_hand, point_hand) for line_hand, point_hand in zip(ax.lines[::3], point_handles)],
          labels=labels, title=ax.legend_.get_title().get_text(), handlelength=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.pointplot with line styles]